# When do I create packages for tag-libs, mappings, etc?

Tags: grails

I'm working through the [Grails In Action](http://www.manning.com/gsmith/) book and have noticed 2 instances that the authors do not create packages for classes.  Specifically, when creating a mapping and a tag-lib.  For instance, the command given to create a tag library is

```
grails create-tag-lib date
```

That gives the output of

```
 Resolving dependencies...
 Dependencies resolved in 641ms.
 Running script C:\grails-1.2.0\scripts\CreateTagLib.groovy
 Environment set to development
 WARNING: You have not specified a package. It is good 
 practise to place classes in packages  (eg. mycompany.Book). 
 Do you want to continue? (y, n)
```

In most other places in the book the authors ensure that controllers and domain classes are declared in packages.  I checked the source as well, and the classes are not in packages.  So, finally, my question.  Is it common practice in Grails, to not put the tag-libs and mappings in packages or was this just an omission by the authors?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an omission. Everything should be in packages.

Comment: I was pretty sure that was the case.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some special case.